# map.values(); returns weird empty "Map Iterator { }" with no values

Tags: javascript

I am following a tutorial, in it a `Map` is created then `map.Value()` is used; this prints all the values of that map, the same as with `map.Keys()`;

When I do it, however, I get this weird empty object `Map Iterator {  }` with no values, and same without keys when I try `map.keys()`:

[Tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxe9n.png)

[Mine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoGMv.png)

Comment: Please show your code. Also please make sure the link is in link format.

Comment: Please provide a link to the tutorial (not an image without context), or at least *quote* the relevant statement from that tutorial.

Comment: Put all the information we need to answer into the question itself, please.  We also don't want _pictures_ of your code, we prefer to see the code itself.  See [Why should I not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever the tutorial claims, the [`values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) method of a `Map` instance does *not* return an array, but an iterator.

You need to consume that iterator to get the actual values:

```js
let mymap = new Map([[1, "a"], [2, "b"], [3, "c"]]);

console.log(mymap.values()); // Wrong: above values are not displayed

console.log(Array.from(mymap.values())); // Create array, or

console.log(...mymap.values()); // Spread as arguments
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know why map.values(); logged the values in the tutorial tho, it is from 2018, so maybe something changed since then?

Comment: No, this has been like this from the time it was introduced in the language with [version ECMAScript 2015](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-map.prototype.values), officially published in June 2015. But if you want me to look into it, then provide a link to the tutorial.

Comment: I found the difference in the browser actually, in Firefox, I get this empty "Map Iterator { }" [link](https://i.imgur.com/DNUbnX9.png) but in Chrome, I can actually see the values [link](https://i.imgur.com/ux2EUkZ.png)

Comment: Yes, that depends on the `console` implementation, which has less strict specifications. Although the Chromium developers probably thought that would be helpful, I think it mostly confuses people. They should just have output the properties of the object.

Comment: holy.. my stupid OTL .. it works really well. Thanks for the answer and also for OP [: